# getting data from xml tags that have : (colon in them)

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, air, rss

I am using AIR to build an application that will search and show the thumbnails from  deviantART the request URL for getting resuts in  form of RSS feed i get the following
for simplicity i am showing the only code in which i have my question

we can use this for   tag

```
trace(myxml.channel.item[0].title);
```

but what to do for tags like media:content

```
trace(myxml.channel.item[0].media:content);
```

but it does not work 
The colons are confusing me

Answer (score 3):

first of all if there are colons in xml that is known namespace otherwise it is simple tag.
so to pasre data from namespace its little different from simple tags.
i can show you some example but if you share the xml format then i can write the appropreate code for you.

here is the sample code:

```
xmlData.ignoreWhitespace=true;
var awsNS:Namespace = new Namespace("http://www.aws.com/aws");
xmlDataVO.state=xmlData..awsNS::["city-state"];
xmlDataVO.country=xmlData..awsNS::["country"];
xmlDataVO.sunriseHour=xmlData..awsNS::sunrise..awsNS::["hour"].@number;
xmlDataVO.sunriseMinute=xmlData..awsNS::sunrise..awsNS::["minute"].@number;
```

my xml format was like this

```
<aws:weather xmlns:aws="http://www.aws.com/aws">
    <aws:city-state citycode="64469">Delhi,  IN</aws:city-state>
    <aws:country>India</aws:country>


    <aws:sunrise>
          <aws:hour number="7" hour-24="07"/>
          <aws:minute number="13"/>
       </aws:sunrise>
 </aws:weather>
```

Answer (score 0):

The colon is used in XML to separate a *namespace* prefix from a *local name* in a fully *qualified* XML name. You can search your documentation for examples on how to deal with XML namespaces.

XML namespaces are declared somewhere in your document using the `xmlns` attribute. If there are prefixed elements (like `media:content`) should have an `xmlns:prefix='namespace'` declaration (like `xmlns:media="some-namespace-uri"`) in the tag you are reading *or* in an ancestor tag (usually, but not always, the root).

You can probably make it work by reading the namespace from your file by its prefix, and assigning it to a variable. Then you use the double-colon to prefix your selector:

```
var media:Namespace = myxml.namespace('media');
trace(myxml.channel.item[0].media::content);
```

Comment: i found **xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"**
should i do like this 
**var media:Namespace = myxml.namespace('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');**

Answer (score -1):

Try to use 
        XML.elements(name:Object):XMLList

package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;

```
public class XmlExample extends Sprite {        
    public function XmlExample() {
        var employees:XML =
            <employees>
                <employee ssn="123-123-1234">
                    <name first="John" last="Doe"/>
                    <address>
                        <street>11 Main St.</street>
                        <city>San Francisco</city>
                        <state>CA</state>
                        <zip>98765</zip>
                    </address>
                </employee>
                <employee ssn="789-789-7890">
                    <name first="Mary" last="Roe"/>
                    <address>
                        <street>99 Broad St.</street>
                        <city>Newton</city>
                        <state>MA</state>
                        <zip>01234</zip>
                    </address>
                </employee>
            </employees>;

        trace(employees.employee[0].address.zip);   // 98765

        trace(employees.employee[1].@ssn);          // 789-789-7890

        trace(employees.employee.name);             // <name first="John" last="Doe"/>
                                                    // <name first="Mary" last="Roe"/>

        trace(employees..zip[0]);                   // 98765

        trace(employees..@ssn[1]);                  // 789-789-7890

        trace(employees..name);                     // <name first="John" last="Doe"/>
                                                    // <name first="Mary" last="Roe"/>

        trace(employees.employee[0].address.*);     // <street>11 Main St.</street>    
                                                    // <city>San Francisco</city>
                                                    // <state>CA</state>
                                                    // <zip>98765</zip>
        var node:String = "zip";
        trace(employees.employee[0].address[node]); // 98765

        var attribute:String = "ssn";
        trace(employees.employee[1].@[attribute]);  // 789-789-7890

        for each (var num:XML in employees..@ssn) {
            trace(num);                             // 123-123-1234
        }                                           // 789-789-7890

        var ssnToFind:String = "789-789-7890";
        trace(employees.employee.(@ssn == ssnToFind).toXMLString());
                                                    // <employee ssn="789-789-7890">
                                                    // <name first="Mary" last="Roe"/>
                                                    // <address>
                                                    // <street>99 Broad St.</street>
                                                    // <city>Newton</city>
                                                    // <state>MA</state>
                                                    // <zip>01234</zip>
                                                    // </address>
                                                    // </employee>
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you did not tell about colons what should i do to them